# Cyrillic app name incorrectly encoded during porting Android app to Blackberry

Tags: android, blackberry-android

I have small problem with displaying cyrillic app name on PlayBook and BB10 simulator. Looks like it's incorrectly encoded from russian. 
Problem appeared after updating bb eclipse plugin from version 1.3 to 1.5, with plugin v.1.3 it worked just ok.

I'll appreciate any help or ideas.

Here is screenshot from bb10 simulator:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found workaround myself.

When I got problems with encodding with bb eclipse plugin, I decided to do the same thing with comandline tools.

After tools setup (sing keys, debug tokens, etc), I've tried to repackage my apk file with this command (source apk file was in apk/ folder and destination for bar file was bar/ folder)

```
./apk2bar apk/ -d bbplaybookdebugtoken.bar -t bar/ -a "zasadnyy" -cg
```

When I've got .bar file, I've installed it with command:

```
/batchbar-deploy bar/ 192.168.1.35 mysecretpass
```

Unfortunatelly result was unsuccsessful, app name was incorrectly encoded again. After first fail I've read documentation a bit more and tried to use this approach: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/creating_a_custom_manifest_file_2016828_11.htm...

When I unzipped bar file and opened `MANIFEST.MS` - I've found this line:

```
Application-Name: –ì–µ—Ä–æ–∏
```

According to documentation solution should be quite strainforward:
1. Rename `MANIFEST.MS` to `<you apk name>.mf`
2. Update incorrect properties, in my case I've changed line from above to `"Application-Name: Герои"`
3. Put edited manifest file in the same folder as `<your apk name>.apk` and rerun `apk2bar` tool with `**-m**` parameter, e.g.:

```
./apk2bar apk/ -d bbplaybookdebugtoken.bar -t bar/ -a "zasadnyy" -m -cg
```

Repackage, deploy, run and ..... and again **FAIL**. Application name was "–ì–µ—Ä–æ–∏".

After second fail, I decided to make dirty hack, I've edited `MANIFEST.MF` directly in repackaged bar file (Unzip -> edit manifest -> zip -> change file extension to .bar).
Deploy updated .bar file to playbook and .... **YEAH**, we've got cyrilic app name!

**Conclusion and FIX:**

- Looks like in 1.5 release if apk2bar tool manifest encoding is misconfigured (in ver. 1.3 it worked just ok)
- In oder to **FIX** issue: Unzip unsigned bar file -> edit manifest -> zip -> change file extension back to .bar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I believe, but the symptoms have been different. I was not even able to install the app on my test device and explicitly running **blackberry-signer -verify** confronted me with the **Invalid signature file digest for Manifest.** error.

The MANIFEST.MF file seems to be properly encoded in utf-8 by the apk2bar tool, but the following signing process seems to read this using the platform's default encoding. I added the following java parameter to the **blackberry-signer.bat** as well as the **apk2bar.bat** batch file scripts of the command line tools to make it work properly:

```
-Dfile-encoding=utf-8
```

(This is for version 1.5.2 of the tools)